# Website HUGE on some mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I have this following website: http://woohooo.fortleet.com/

Everything is OK, except the site opens up HUGE on some mobile browsers/devices. This mainly happens on:

- iPhone 6S (Safari and Messenger)
- Mozilla on Android (sometimes)

Examples:

[image]
[image]

I have NO IDEA what could cause this. I don't have any scripts handling the height of elements, all sections are set to be 100vh.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`vh` is buggy in many mobile browsers, especially in IOS.
There is a js library to fix this: https://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill